# Acer monitor inbuilt speaker option not working on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hdmi, sound-volume

I am using a MacBook Pro with an Acer monitor, but I am not getting audio output.
I also tried selecting a speaker from the Menu Bar (attached screenshot)

However, when I saw on the Acer page it showed it has an inbuilt speaker of 2W.

[image: Screenshot of the Sound Menu Item dropdown menu showing the Mac internal speakers and the Acer KG241Q S monitor]

How can I fix this?

[Acer KG241Q Widescreen LCD Monitor](https://www.acer.com/gb-en/monitors/gaming/nitro-kg1/pdp/UM.UX1EE.001)

> Audio Speakers: Yes Speaker Output Power: 2 W

Comment: Is the volume turned up *on the monitor side*?

Comment: @JMY1000 There is no volume control option from Monitor side

Comment: That's not true. The manual clearly states there's a volume control [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeYZL.png).

Comment: @JMY1000 hmm. In manual it's there but I can't see volume option in monitor, seems like it supports for windows only :( 
May be issue with Mac Drivers

Answer (score 1):

Restart your MacBook and immediately press and hold <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
Hold the keys until you hear the startup sound for the second time, then release.

Or try to connect the monitor to another device (e.g., another computer or a gaming console) to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I think issue is with connecting with mac only